# Have any viruses leveraging the GPU been discovered in the wild? What is the mitigation?

Tags: web-browser, antivirus, antimalware, defense, threat-mitigation

[This news article from 2010](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/09/28/gpu_assisted_malware/) discusses how a GPU can be used by a virus to avoid detection by common anti-malware/anti-virus software. The idea is to obfuscate the virus payload and leverage the GPU's computing power to unpack it, thus defeating a signature-based antivirus that is limited by CPU computing power.

- Has there been any documented instances of viruses leveraging the GPU occurring in the wild?
- How have antivirus and antimalware vendors responded to this threat?
- Does this mean WebGL and WebCL is another vector for exploit?

Comment: GPU viruses - that's an odd question. What's a CPU virus ?

Comment: it's an interesting idea... a GPU virus may leverage bugs in graphics driver... but it will need to support at least the 3 major vendor (nvidia, ATI.. ehm... AMD, and Intel)

Comment: @RoryAlsop The article cited here is not about a GPU virus, but about a CPU virus that only uses the GPU to leverage its computational power.

Comment: Might I suggest looking for a cached version of the [VX Heavens](http://vx.netlux.org/index.html) website. This was, by far, one of the best VX resources on the web.

Comment: See our [survey paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.00114.pdf) on attacks and security techniques for GPUs. It discusses GPU-based malware, use of GPU for keylogging, and many other techniques.

Answer (score 5):

The first GPU-assisted malware is considered to be [the Badminer trojan reported by Semantec in 2011](http://www.pcr-online.biz/news/read/new-malware-makes-money-from-your-gpu/019391). Although its GPU leverage level is pretty low and the risk is low too, this is still the first precedence of using the GPU maliciously in the wild.

Another more intrusive example of the same idea is [RiskTool.Win32.BitCoinMiner](http://deletemalware.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/remove-risktoolwin32bitcoinminer.html).

Then [antivirus designers started to think really hard](http://techblog.avira.com/2010/11/09/gpu-acceleration-in-the-malware-scene/en/). No AV vendor will invent effective GPU-related protection until high-risk GPU-assisted malware starts to appear in large volume *and* more traditional AV approaches fail. It won't happen very soon. Meanwhile, it's just not feasible to protect against a still imaginary danger.

*Everything* is a potential attack vector as soon as it becomes more and more profitable. There's no such thing in the world that is not attackable or misusable in some form. Regarding particular WebCL, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebCL): "Currently, no browsers natively support WebCL, seeing as it is new. However, non-native add-ons are used to implement WebCL."

Comment: Wasn't quite a virus but a bunch of online gaming community users had their GPU's hijacked to mine bitcoins (I was one of them) the company I probably shouldn't name as they have rectified the situation (a rougue employee added the code to their server browser program) - just a little extra info!

Comment: I believe you're talking about E-Sports Entertainment game developer as this article http://www.commercehousewirral.co.uk/commerce-house-wirral-latest-news/7-news/17359-e-sports-settles-bitcoin-hijack-case.html describes your case. I don't see any point to refrain from naming/shaming/blaming as our planet simply must know its "heroes". Note, that it's still conventional malware requiring conventional Intel code to become active and proceed, so it's perfectly detectable by conventional AV solutions

Comment: Ah, in that case the company was ESEA. (http://play.esea.net/)